# Disabling a type="image" input won't work on Firefox

Tags: html

I am trying to disable a button I made for a game. When I open the game in all the other browsers, the button is disabled. But, when I open the game in Firefox, the button is not disabled. If I switch the input type to "button", the button disables. Here is the code:

`<input type="image" src="mapIcon.png" alt="mapIcon" class="mapIcon" id="mapIcon" onclick="openMap()" disabled>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71659876/the-buttons-disabled-attribute-doesnt-work-in-firefox-after-the-refresh-f5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is a dupe, but found the answer within 5 seconds of searching.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3447442/19447792

`document.getElementbyId(ID).setAttribute('disabled', true|false);` Works on IE/FF/GC

So:

```html
<input type="image" src="mapIcon.png" alt="mapIcon" class="mapIcon" id="mapIcon" onclick="openMap()">

<script>
#disable
document.getElementbyId('mapIcon').setAttribute('disabled', true);

#enable
document.getElementbyId('mapIcon').setAttribute('disabled', false);
</script>
```

Comment: If the question is a duplicate, you should vote to close it for that reason. Do not answer duplicate questions! [answer]

Comment: I did vote but no action taken.